# Generalized du Bios-Reymond Lemma

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone give me some hint on the following problem? Many thanks!

If $h\in C[a,b]$ and for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\int_a^b h(x)v^{(m)}(x)\,dx=0$ for all $v$ $m$-times continuously differentiable and $v^{(k)}(a)=v^{(k)}(b)=0$ for all $k=0,1,\dots, m-1$, then $h$ is a polynomial with degree less than or equal to $m-1$ on $[a,b]$.

I guess a smart use of integration by parts may solve this problem, but I failed to make that since I do not know whether $h$ is differentiable.

Comment: I think that the Theorem 1.2 in (http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/bcp/bcp35/bcp35117.pdf) and reference therein would correspond to your need.